# Xpath: Selecting all of an element type?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm just starting to learn Xpath, I'm trying to write a line of code that will select all of the actors in EACH movie parent (through Java!). Below, I have an example of one movie, but there are multiple `<Movie>` elements, each with `<Actor>` elements.

```
<Movie Genre = 'Other'>
    <Title>Requiem For A Dream</Title>
    <ReleaseYear>2000</ReleaseYear>
    <Director>Darren Aronofsky</Director>
    <Actor Character = 'Sara Goldfarb'>Ellen Burstyn</Actor>
    <Actor Character = 'Harry Goldfarb'>Jared Leto</Actor>
    <Actor Character = 'Marion Silver'>Jennifer Connelly</Actor>
    <Actor Character = 'Tyrone C. Love'>Marlon Wayans</Actor>
</Movie>
```

Currently, I can only select the first `<Actor>` element of each `<Movie>` element -- is it possible to select all of them without using a for loop?

Here is my current line of code that displays the first `<Actor>` element of every `<Movie>` element:

`System.out.println("Starring: " + xpath.evaluate("Actor", movieNode) + " as " + xpath.evaluate("Actor/@Character", movieNode) + "\n");`

Any and all help if much appreciated!

Comment: @Johannes: It's not clear to me what you want to do. Do you want to select every `Actor` element in the whole document? Or do you want to select every `Actor` element children of some `Movie` element in context?

Comment: I haven't used XPath in Java before but I'm guessing that you will need to change the return type to be NodeSet rather than String (use the overload of `evaluate()`). That being said there may be a library that wraps the API in something a little nicer - casting objects... yuck! Oh, by the way the expression to select all Actor elements anywhere in the document would be `//Actor`

Comment: @Alejandro: Every child element of every movie.

Comment: @CurtainDog: //Actor only selects the FIRST child node of every movie element.

Comment: @Johannes: No, `//Actor` selects EVERY `Actor` node in the entire document. However, as I mentioned in my answer, you need to evaluate it as a `NodeSet` and use a for loop to process each result.

Comment: @JG: I think the OP was more worried about looping over the expression rather than looping over the results, but your answer is right.

Comment: I realize that //Actor should traditionally select all Actor nodes, it just doesn't in this case. It seems as though a loop is required. Thanks!

Comment: Note if you use an XPath 2.0 implementation like Saxon 9 from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ then you should be able to use an XPath expression like `xpath.evaluate("string-join(Actor, ', ')", movieNode)` respectively `xpath.evaluate("string-join(Actor/@Character, ', ')", movieNode)`. That way you don't need a loop in Java, you can build your string of values with XPath itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need a for loop to iterate over each `Node` in a `NodeList` returned by the `evaluate` method.

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate("Actor", movieNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  Element actor = (Element)nodes.item(i);
  String actorName = actor.getTextContent();
  String character = actor.getAttribute("Character");
  System.out.println("Starring: " + actorName + " as " + character + "\n");
}
```

PS: Good movie btw :-).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great start! The actor's name is returning as Null, but it's printing out all the character names. Which seems odd, but I'll work through it. Thanks so much! (Also, just a small note, it should be "XPathConstants" -- just a small typo!)

Comment: Right, it should be `getTextContent` instead; `getNodeValue` returns `null` for Nodes of type `Element`. Thanks for pointing out, it should work fine now.